# Having some trouble with a guessing game I have for an assignment in Java

Tags: java

This is just a small assignment for an intro Comp Sci class I have but I'm having some troubles with a part where I have to prompt the user for verification of a guess that the code makes and then if it's wrong it will prompt if it's higher or lower and so on. I wanted to make it so if the max range of numbers is 12, I would start from 6 and from there I would ask the user first: If it's correct? and if not then ask if it's higher or lower. Depending on his answer my next value would be between 0 and 6, which is 3, or 6 and 12, which is 9. I've tried multiple different ways and have searched online for some tips but no luck. If you can help me out with my code or can guide me to an answer that would be great!

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
boolean guess = false;

int maxMonth = 12;
int minMonth = 0;
int month = (maxMonth - minMonth) / 2;
int total = 6;

while (guess == false) {
    String yes = "yes";
    String no = "no";
    int tries = 0;
    boolean firstGuess = false;

    System.out.println("Is your birthday in " + month + " yes or no:");
    String a1 = in.next();

    if (a1.equals(yes)) {
        firstGuess = true;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Is your birthday after this month?");
        String a2 = in.next();

        if (a2.equals(yes)) {
            total++;
            total = (int) total / 2;
            month = month + total;
        } else {
            total = total - 3;
            total = (int) total / 2;
            month = month + total;
        }
    }

    //guesses the day in the month
    while (firstGuess == true) { }
}
```

Comment: Are you allowed to use trees? You could do a binary search tree and go left or right based on if it’s higher or lower

Comment: Binary search does not require a tree - just saying. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm

Comment: Do it in the code as you would do it in your head, or in your explanations: You have a lower bound and a higher bound (initially 1 and 12). You guess by taking the middle number of that range. If it's correct, you exit. If it's lower, you change the bounds to [guess + 1, higherBound]  (i.e. [7, 12] and you continue. If it's higher, you change the bounds to [lowerBound, guess - 1] (i.e. [1, 5]) and you continue.

Comment: Basically, your idea is OK - you are just making the wrong calculations. Remember that "half of the range" is relative - at the start, "half" is 6, but as your guesses come closer, the "half" also shrinks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to calculate the value of month inside the loop.  After each guess, if a2 is yes then update minMonth = month + 1, and if a2 if no update maxMonth = month - 1, and loop again (recalculating month = (maxMonth - minMonth) / 2).

Also the condition for your loop is **while (guess == false)** but you never change the value of guess, so you can never exit the loop.  You need  **if (a1.equals(yes)) guess = true;**  (not firstGuess).